# I've been following react video tutorial and I am having "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error

Tags: reactjs

I am unsure what to do with this error message. What does it mean and how do I fix this?

> "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

The code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import Result from './Result'

function Results({ results }) {
    return (
        <section className="results">
            {results.map(result => (
                <Result result={result} />
            ))}
        </section>
    )
}

export default Results
```

Comment: So, you have something that is most likely asynchronous in nature. And that hasn't loaded as of yet. default results to an empty array. `function Results({ results = [] })`

Comment: Thanks @John Ruddell. It woked

Comment: Great! glad I could help! I also wrote it up as an answer with some more detail :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly clear. "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Meaning in your `results.map` call... results is undefined. This means you're expecting it to be something that it isn't (at least on the first render cycle).

You are most likely experiencing an asynchronous loading time for some data / results from an API call. To handle the inflight part, you can default the `results` to an empty array

```
function Results({ results = [] }) { 
  return (
    <section className="results">
        {results.map(result => (
            <Result result={result} />
        ))}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Another thing you can do is verify you have an array to be extra careful.

```
function Results({ results = [] }) { 
  if (!Array.isArray(results)) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <section className="results">
        {results.map(result => (
            <Result result={result} />
        ))}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Results component expects `results` prop. So in order to make it work, you need to use Result component like this:

```
<Results results={[1, 2, 3, 4]} />
```